# Linear transformations: Proof relation of dimensions

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation.

Proof that

**a) If $f$ is injective, $\dim(V) \leq \dim(W)$**

If $f$ is injective, then $f(v_1), ..., f(v_n)$ for a basis $v_1, ..., v_n$ of $V$ form a basis of $f(V)$. Since $f(V) \subseteq W$, we can conclude that $\dim(V) \leq \dim(W)$. ◻

**b) If $f$ is surjective, $\dim(V) \geq \dim(W)$**

If $f$ is surjective, then $f(v_1), ..., f(v_n)$ for a basis $v_1, ..., v_n$ of $V$ form a generator of $W$. Since a generator *can* be linearly dependent (thus contains more vectors than a basis of $W$), we conclude that $\dim(V) \geq \dim(W)$. ◻

Please give me hints if these are correct proofs. The example solutions use different approaches.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly fine, and if you are completely convinced by your arguments, then that is enough :-)

Comment: It sounds good to me. Well done!